# Groovy: setPropertyValue()

Tags: groovy

I need to update a value in the property test step. Dynamically I am getting value in 'abc' parameter and 'line1' value need to update in 'abc' parameter in Properties test step.

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties1").setPropertyValue(%s,"abc",line1)
```

This is giving an error message.

following is the Error msg,

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script99.groovy: 19: expecting EOF, found '(' @ line 19, column 70. Properties1").setPropertyValue(%s,"abc", ^ 
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting EOF, found '(' @ line 19, column 70. at 
org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:107) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:163) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:839) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:544) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:520) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:770) at 
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:761) at 
com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at 
com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:148) at 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Script99.groovy:19:70: expecting EOF, found '(' at 
groovyjarjarantlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:780) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:130) ... 20 more 1 error
```

Comment: Please add your error Message

Comment: its with the content. pls help

Answer (score 2):

*I fixed your question - you may want take the time to [understand how to format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Your error message was being hidden because it was inside html brackets, and also it was all one line, making it hard to read.*

As for the error, it is a compilation error (`MultipleCompilationErrorsException`).  This means that the code itself is invalid.

Simply looking at your code, I see this:

```
.setPropertyValue(%s,"abc",line1)
                  ^^
```

The marked value is not valid Groovy code.  I don't know what you were going for, but it looks like it was copied and pasted here from something else.  You probably meant:

```
.setPropertyValue("abc", line1)
```

Fix this, and you might be able to get your code to compile.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I understand this is the error. see my qn, [I need to update a value in the property test step. Dynamically I need to access value in 'abc' parameter and 'line1' value need to update in 'abc' parameter in Properties test step.]

Answer (score 2):

The below line of code would help,

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties Test Step Name").getProperty("Prop1").setValue("MyValue")
```

or to set up property if it does not exist

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties Test Step Name"].setPropertyValue( "Prop1", "MyValue" )
```

I've tested this in my code, it will work fine.